# problem with justify-content on react native

Tags: css, react-native, justify

the text isnt be o center of the button.

from what I noticed, the text line stays but not the text itself

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {BaseButton} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export const Container = styled(BaseButton)`
  justify-content: center;
  height: 46px;
  align-items: center;
  background: #3b9eff;
  border-radius: 4px;
`;

export const Text = styled.Text`
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
`;
```

[Text not centralized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCBKQ.png)

Comment: Is your button a flexbox? Otherwise justify-content will not get applied.

Comment: im beginner on RN. my button is a component that i will use sometimes. im not shure if this is a flexbox. how can i do this right?

Comment: Add `display: flex;` after the line of `justify: center` and see if that helps

Comment: I tried this before, it doesn't work. so bizarre, I practically copied and pasted from an example and it doesn't work.